# SearchBar Cuts off inside navigationbar

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisearchbar

I am working on pretty simple animation in navigation bar: I have navigationbar bar with 2 buttons on the (right). On search icon tap I animate nav bar so it hides both button and search icon and shows  search bar. On cancel button tap it does the opposite. Simple

[image]

```
 lazy var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 140/255, green: 195/255, blue: 65/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

}

On tap of search button search bar is added to navigation bar,but its slightly cut's off on the left as well as right side.

```
 @IBAction func subjectTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(nil, animated: true)
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems(nil,animated: true)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = nil
    searchBar.placeholder = "I am looking for ..."
    searchBar.alpha = 0
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.searchBar.alpha = 1
    }, completion: { finished in
        self.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    })

}
```

Please tell me what am i doing wrong and whats the fix for this problem